# Regex with sign

Tags: regex

I need a simple regex for numbers only [0-9] but it must be a number with length 19 and can have optional "-" sign:

Correct Example:

```
-1234567890123456789
```

Correct Example 2:

```
1234567890123456789
```

Any idea how to start?

Comment: OK. What do you have so far and what part is giving you trouble? If you don't tell us what you have tried, we will likely give you solutions you have already tried. Also, what regex flavor is this for? POSIX basic regular expressions? Extended regular expressions? PCRE? Something else?

Comment: something like ^[0-9]{19}$ could be a solution

Comment: Not if you are using POSIX BRE. That will work with PCRE or ERE. It all depends on the family of regular expressions you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
-?\d{19}
```

It has an optional "-" sign and then 19 digits.